# How to disable SSLv3 in android for HttpsUrlConnection?

Tags: java, android, client, httpsurlconnection, poodle-attack

We wrote client application in android which connects with https servers using HttpsUrlConnection apis. Due to Poodle vulnerability, we need to disable SSLv3 from the list of enabled protocols while invoking any request.

We followed the [guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/cve-2014-3566-2342133.html) captured by oracle

and added following line before invoking url connection

```
java.lang.System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1");
```

This solution works fine with normal java program. 
We got `SSLHandShakeException` when tried to connect with a server which only works on SSLv3 protocol.

**But concern is** : same fix does not work for android. Am I missing something or should I try another approach for android? Please suggest.

Comment: did you try to create own SSLContext and pass its SocketFactory to the HttpsUrlConnection ?

Comment: Can you share a service url which only supports SSLv3 connection?

Comment: Hi Selvin,not tried with SSLContext. I will try and update you. Any quick pointer/code snippet will be great.

Answer (score 48):

I found the solution for it by analyzing the data packets using wireshark. What I found is that while making a secure connection, android was falling back to **SSLv3** from **TLSv1** . It is a bug in android versions < 4.4 , and it can be solved by removing the SSLv3 protocol from Enabled Protocols list. I made a custom socketFactory class called NoSSLv3SocketFactory.java. Use this to make a socketfactory.

```
/*Copyright 2015 Bhavit Singh Sengar
Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.*/

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.HandshakeCompletedListener;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;


public class NoSSLv3SocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory{
    private final SSLSocketFactory delegate;

public NoSSLv3SocketFactory() {
    this.delegate = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
}

public NoSSLv3SocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    return delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
}

private Socket makeSocketSafe(Socket socket) {
    if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
        socket = new NoSSLv3SSLSocket((SSLSocket) socket);
    }
    return socket;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return makeSocketSafe(delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
}

private class NoSSLv3SSLSocket extends DelegateSSLSocket {

    private NoSSLv3SSLSocket(SSLSocket delegate) {
        super(delegate);

    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] protocols) {
        if (protocols != null && protocols.length == 1 && "SSLv3".equals(protocols[0])) {

            List<String> enabledProtocols = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(delegate.getEnabledProtocols()));
            if (enabledProtocols.size() > 1) {
                enabledProtocols.remove("SSLv3");
                System.out.println("Removed SSLv3 from enabled protocols");
            } else {
                System.out.println("SSL stuck with protocol available for " + String.valueOf(enabledProtocols));
            }
            protocols = enabledProtocols.toArray(new String[enabledProtocols.size()]);
        }

        super.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
    }
}

public class DelegateSSLSocket extends SSLSocket {

    protected final SSLSocket delegate;

    DelegateSSLSocket(SSLSocket delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getEnabledCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getEnabledCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabledCipherSuites(String[] suites) {
        delegate.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedProtocols() {
        return delegate.getSupportedProtocols();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getEnabledProtocols() {
        return delegate.getEnabledProtocols();
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnabledProtocols(String[] protocols) {
        delegate.setEnabledProtocols(protocols);
    }

    @Override
    public SSLSession getSession() {
        return delegate.getSession();
    }

    @Override
    public void addHandshakeCompletedListener(HandshakeCompletedListener listener) {
        delegate.addHandshakeCompletedListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeHandshakeCompletedListener(HandshakeCompletedListener listener) {
        delegate.removeHandshakeCompletedListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void startHandshake() throws IOException {
        delegate.startHandshake();
    }

    @Override
    public void setUseClientMode(boolean mode) {
        delegate.setUseClientMode(mode);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getUseClientMode() {
        return delegate.getUseClientMode();
    }

    @Override
    public void setNeedClientAuth(boolean need) {
        delegate.setNeedClientAuth(need);
    }

    @Override
    public void setWantClientAuth(boolean want) {
        delegate.setWantClientAuth(want);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getNeedClientAuth() {
        return delegate.getNeedClientAuth();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getWantClientAuth() {
        return delegate.getWantClientAuth();
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnableSessionCreation(boolean flag) {
        delegate.setEnableSessionCreation(flag);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getEnableSessionCreation() {
        return delegate.getEnableSessionCreation();
    }

    @Override
    public void bind(SocketAddress localAddr) throws IOException {
        delegate.bind(localAddr);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
        delegate.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void connect(SocketAddress remoteAddr) throws IOException {
        delegate.connect(remoteAddr);
    }

    @Override
    public void connect(SocketAddress remoteAddr, int timeout) throws IOException {
        delegate.connect(remoteAddr, timeout);
    }

    @Override
    public SocketChannel getChannel() {
        return delegate.getChannel();
    }

    @Override
    public InetAddress getInetAddress() {
        return delegate.getInetAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        return delegate.getInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getKeepAlive() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getKeepAlive();
    }

    @Override
    public InetAddress getLocalAddress() {
        return delegate.getLocalAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public int getLocalPort() {
        return delegate.getLocalPort();
    }

    @Override
    public SocketAddress getLocalSocketAddress() {
        return delegate.getLocalSocketAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getOOBInline() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getOOBInline();
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
        return delegate.getOutputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public int getPort() {
        return delegate.getPort();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int getReceiveBufferSize() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getReceiveBufferSize();
    }

    @Override
    public SocketAddress getRemoteSocketAddress() {
        return delegate.getRemoteSocketAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getReuseAddress() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getReuseAddress();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int getSendBufferSize() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getSendBufferSize();
    }

    @Override
    public int getSoLinger() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getSoLinger();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized int getSoTimeout() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getSoTimeout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getTcpNoDelay() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getTcpNoDelay();
    }

    @Override
    public int getTrafficClass() throws SocketException {
        return delegate.getTrafficClass();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBound() {
        return delegate.isBound();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isClosed() {
        return delegate.isClosed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConnected() {
        return delegate.isConnected();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInputShutdown() {
        return delegate.isInputShutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isOutputShutdown() {
        return delegate.isOutputShutdown();
    }

    @Override
    public void sendUrgentData(int value) throws IOException {
        delegate.sendUrgentData(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setKeepAlive(boolean keepAlive) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setKeepAlive(keepAlive);
    }

    @Override
    public void setOOBInline(boolean oobinline) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setOOBInline(oobinline);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPerformancePreferences(int connectionTime, int latency, int bandwidth) {
        delegate.setPerformancePreferences(connectionTime, latency, bandwidth);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setReceiveBufferSize(int size) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setReceiveBufferSize(size);
    }

    @Override
    public void setReuseAddress(boolean reuse) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setReuseAddress(reuse);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setSendBufferSize(int size) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setSendBufferSize(size);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSoLinger(boolean on, int timeout) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setSoLinger(on, timeout);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setSoTimeout(int timeout) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setSoTimeout(timeout);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTcpNoDelay(boolean on) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setTcpNoDelay(on);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTrafficClass(int value) throws SocketException {
        delegate.setTrafficClass(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdownInput() throws IOException {
        delegate.shutdownInput();
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdownOutput() throws IOException {
        delegate.shutdownOutput();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return delegate.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return delegate.equals(o);
    }
}
}
```

Use this class like this while connecting :

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");

            sslcontext.init(null,
                    null,
                    null);
            SSLSocketFactory NoSSLv3Factory = new NoSSLv3SocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(NoSSLv3Factory);
            l_connection = (HttpsURLConnection) l_url.openConnection();
            l_connection.connect();
```

**UPDATE :**

Now, correct solution would be to install a newer security provider using [Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller.html):

```
    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());
```

This effectively gives your app access to a newer version of OpenSSL and Java Security Provider, which includes support for TLSv1.2 in SSLEngine. Once the new provider is installed, you can create an SSLEngine which supports SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 the usual way:

```
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    sslContext.init(null, null, null);
    SSLEngine engine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
```

Or you can restrict the enabled protocols using `engine.setEnabledProtocols`.

Don't forget to add the following dependency ([latest version found here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
```

For more info, checkout this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html).

Comment: Thankyou! Your solution was perfect to enable TLS v1.2 using okhttp 2.3.0 for phones lower than version 20.

Comment: What do you mean by "Enabled Protocols List"? Is it something like a setting I can find in a file like Android Manifest? If I just want to disable the SSLv3, do I have to take your class "NoSSLv3SocketFactory" and use it in my code instead of the current implementation. Sorry I'm confused and a newbie.

Comment: Every android version supports a range of protocols, you can check it out here http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)

Comment: Your code is not working, because `setEnabledProtocols` is not being called and because of the check `protocols.length == 1`

Comment: shouldn't the above snippet also set the TLS version to `TLSv1.2` instead of `TLSv1`?

Comment: You definitely saved my day! I faced this problem and tried quite some different solutions and none of them worked (like specifying TLSv1.1 etc). Your solution, removing the SSLv3 from the supported protocols, worked out well and didn't break on any other device. Funny thing, it worked on all devices before, but not the Galaxy S3 Mini from Samsung...

Comment: @BhavitS.Sengar how can i use it in loopj get request/in Ion get

Comment: For reference, the bug in question: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78187

Comment: I just wish I would have found your answer days ago! Thanks!

Comment: I just used  ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext()); and it solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Inspired by Bhavit S. Sengar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29946540/306864), it bundled that technique into a dead simple method call. You can use the [NetCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/netcipher) library to get a modern TLS config when using Android's `HttpsURLConnection`.  NetCipher configures the `HttpsURLConnection` instance to use the best supported TLS version, removes SSLv3 support, and configures the best suite of ciphers for that TLS version.  First, add it to your *build.gradle*:

```
compile 'info.guardianproject.netcipher:netcipher:1.2'
```

Or you can download the *netcipher-1.2.jar* and include it directly in your app.  Then instead of calling:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) sourceUrl.openConnection();
```

Call this:

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = NetCipher.getHttpsURLConnection(sourceUrl);
```

Comment: What if I want to use OKHttp?

Comment: I tried this, and I am getting the net cipher sslsocketfactory, but, the SSLv3 protocol is still showing when inspecting it in the debugger. This is on android 5.1. Everything I've tried, including my own custom sslsocketfactory class where I either disable SSLv3 or only enable TLS... is resulting in this; the SSLv3 protocol still shows.

Comment: Is this lib the same as using the NoSSLv3 socket mentioned in the selected answer or is it different in any way?

Comment: Yeah, it uses a very similar approach as `NoSSLv3SocketFactory`

Comment: We're working on adding support for OkHTTP, Volley, and Apache HttpClient for Android to the same NetCipher library.

Comment: @Hans-ChristophSteiner will this enable TLS support for Android versions below 4.1?

Comment: TLS v1.0 has been supported by Android since the first version, so this disables SSLv2 and SSLv3 support.  `android-20` is the first Android version to support TLS v1.1 and v1.2.  https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html

Comment: NetCipher now supports OkHTTP, Volley, etc.  Get it with _gradle_ using: `compile 'info.guardianproject.netcipher:netcipher-okhttp3:2.0.0-alpha1'`

Comment: Does it support Apache HttpClient

Comment: Yes, you can use it with ch.boye HttpClient or Apache HttpClient for Android

Answer (score 6):

At first I tried Bhavit S. Sengar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649389/how-to-disable-sslv3-in-android-for-httpsurlconnection/29946540#29946540) and it worked for most cases. But sometimes there where issues even when SSLv3 protocol was removed from Enabled Protocols on an Android 4.4.4 device. So the [NetCipher](https://guardianproject.info/code/netcipher) library by Hans-Christoph Steiner is perfect to solve that problem as far as I could test it.

We use jsoup to make a bunch of web scraping on different servers, so we cannot set `HttpsURLConnection connection = NetCipher.getHttpsURLConnection(sourceUrl);`. I assume that's the same problem if you use OkHttp.

The best solution we've come to is to set the `info.guardianproject.netcipher.client.TlsOnlySocketFactory` from NetCipher as `DefaultSSLSocketFactory` in a static block. So it's set for the whole runtime of our app:

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
sslcontext.init(null, null, null);
SSLSocketFactory noSSLv3Factory = new TlsOnlySocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(noSSLv3Factory);
```

If you like to inspect the full details (with `trustAllCertificates`) you can do it [here](https://github.com/MyGrades/mygrades-app/blob/master/app/src/main/java/de/mygrades/main/core/Scraper.java#L87).

Comment: shouldn't this be `TLSv1.2`?

Comment: Thank you very much bro ! you made my day !

Comment: still SSLHandshakeException

Answer (score 4):

use this code snippet, if server is SSLv3 enable then it will fail handshaking.

```
        SocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket("host-name", 443);
        socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] { "TLSv1"});
        socket.startHandshake();
```

Comment: I still get a `javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake failed` error.

Comment: It should be TLSv1.2

Answer (score 0):

```
 SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
                sslContext.init(null, null, null);
                SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
                            httpURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
```

**HttpsURLConnection using TSL create a security failed, the Android implementation will fall back to SSLV3 to connection.**

Please refer this *http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78431*

Comment: Why are you initing sslContext with all nulls?

Answer (score 0):

Using [PlayService publisher client libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/androidpublisher/v1) running on Android I experienced the same problem when running the [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/tree/master/v2/java).

Fixed it with @bhavit-s-sengar's awnser above.  Had to also change `AndroidPublisherHelper.newTrustedTransport()` to this:

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
sslcontext.init(null, null, null);
//  NoSSLv3SocketFactory is @bhavit-s-sengar's http://stackoverflow.com/a/29946540/8524
SSLSocketFactory noSSLv3Factory = new NoSSLv3SocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());

NetHttpTransport.Builder netTransportBuilder = new NetHttpTransport.Builder();
netTransportBuilder.setSslSocketFactory(noSSLv3Factory);
HTTP_TRANSPORT = netTransportBuilder.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Connects with https server we need certificate in handshaking from client side. 1 year back I solved a similar issue using self sign certificate in the following way-

```
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class HttpsTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

private static TrustManager[] trustManagers;
private static final X509Certificate[] _AcceptedIssuers = new X509Certificate[]{};

@Override
public void checkClientTrusted(
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
        throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {

}

@Override
public void checkServerTrusted(
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
        throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {

}

public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
    return true;
}

public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    return _AcceptedIssuers;
}

public static void allowAllSSL() {
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

        @Override
        public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
            return true;
        }

    });

    SSLContext context = null;
    if (trustManagers == null) {
        trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{new HttpsTrustManager()};
    }

    try {
        context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context
            .getSocketFactory());
}

}
```

Usage in client side before HttpsUrlConnection

```
HttpsTrustManager.allowAllSSL();
```

hopefully it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually we don't need to disable the SSLV3 or TLSV1.0, What we just need to enable TLSV1.1 or TLSv1.2 in android < 5 devices.

The problem is TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 not enabled on Android <5 by default and to connect using these latest secure protocol we must have to enable in Android <5 devices.

This solution fixed my problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45853669/3448003