# How to enable TLS 1.2 support in an Android application (running on Android 4.1 JB)

Tags: android, ssl, https

As per the docs in Android for `SSLSocket` and `SSLContext`, TLS v1.1 and v1.2 protocols are supported in API level 16+, but are not enabled by default.
http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html

How do I enable it on a device running Android 4.1 or later (but below 5.0)?

I have tried creating a custom SSLSocketFactory which enables all the supported protocols when `Socket`'s are created and later use my custom implementation as:

> HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(new MySSLSocketFactory());

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
        
        private SSLContext sc;
        private SSLSocketFactory ssf;  
        
        public MySSLSocketFactory() {
            try {
                sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                sc.init(null, null, null);
                ssf = sc.getSocketFactory();

            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
        }
        
        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose)
                throws IOException {
            SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose);
            ss.setEnabledProtocols(ss.getSupportedProtocols());
            ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(ss.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            return ss;
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
            return ssf.getDefaultCipherSuites();
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
            return ssf.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket(host, port);
            ss.setEnabledProtocols(ss.getSupportedProtocols());
            ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(ss.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            return ss;
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
            SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket(host, port);
            ss.setEnabledProtocols(ss.getSupportedProtocols());
            ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(ss.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            return ss;
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort)
                throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort);
            ss.setEnabledProtocols(ss.getSupportedProtocols());
            ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(ss.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            return ss;
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress,
                int localPort) throws IOException {
            SSLSocket ss = (SSLSocket) ssf.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort);
            ss.setEnabledProtocols(ss.getSupportedProtocols());
            ss.setEnabledCipherSuites(ss.getSupportedCipherSuites());
            return ss;
        }
    }
```

But it still gives an exception while trying to establish a connection with a server on which **Only TLS 1.2** is enabled.

Here is the exception I get:

> 03-09 09:21:38.427: W/System.err(2496):
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:
> ssl=0xb7fa0620: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>
> 03-09 09:21:38.427: W/System.err(2496): error:14077410:SSL
> routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
> (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0xa90e6990:0x00000000)

Comment: In my testing I found that while TLSv1.2 is available and can be enabled on API 16-18, there are still problems with specific uses such as providing client certificates, even after including Play Services. 
No solution yet.

Comment: What makes this even more confusing is that SSLEngine states support for TLS1.1/1.2 is only in API20+. http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine.html

Answer (score 20):

2 ways to enable TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2:

1. use this guideline:
   http://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/
2. use this class 
   https://github.com/erickok/transdroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/transdroid/daemon/util/TlsSniSocketFactory.java
   `schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", new TlsSniSocketFactory(), port));`

Comment: I used your second suggestion as such and I am facing issues. In createSocket() method of TlsSniSocketFactory class, the SSL Session returned is invalid. I don't know why but this is happening in API 17 as well as API 24 device ? Please have a look at my detailed query about it please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684898/why-does-createsocket-returns-invalid-session-in-sslsession

Comment: Thank you so much! This saved me big time!

Comment: Using first option,with httpclient but getting old v1.0, actually want v1.2. private HttpClient getTheHttpClient(HttpParams httpParameters) {
     SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
     try {
         registry.register(new Scheme("https", new TLSSocketFactory(), 443));
     } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(httpParameters, registry),httpParameters);

     return  client;
 }

Answer (score 14):

I solved this issue following the indication provided in the article  http://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/ with little changes.

```
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, null, null);
SSLSocketFactory noSSLv3Factory = null;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    noSSLv3Factory = new TLSSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
} else {
    noSSLv3Factory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
}
connection.setSSLSocketFactory(noSSLv3Factory);
```

This is the code of the custom TLSSocketFactory:

```
public static class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

    public TLSSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory delegate) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        internalSSLSocketFactory = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    /*
     * Utility methods
     */

    private static Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
        if (socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)
                && isTLSServerEnabled((SSLSocket) socket)) { // skip the fix if server doesn't provide there TLS version
            ((SSLSocket) socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{TLS_v1_1, TLS_v1_2});
        }
        return socket;
    }

    private static boolean isTLSServerEnabled(SSLSocket sslSocket) {
        System.out.println("__prova__ :: " + sslSocket.getSupportedProtocols().toString());
        for (String protocol : sslSocket.getSupportedProtocols()) {
            if (protocol.equals(TLS_v1_1) || protocol.equals(TLS_v1_2)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Edit: Thank's to ademar111190 for the kotlin implementation ([link](https://gist.github.com/ademar111190/052de9e03f62bb0b2f4063c39774c79f))

```
class TLSSocketFactory constructor(
        private val internalSSLSocketFactory: SSLSocketFactory
) : SSLSocketFactory() {

    private val protocols = arrayOf("TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1")

    override fun getDefaultCipherSuites(): Array<String> = internalSSLSocketFactory.defaultCipherSuites

    override fun getSupportedCipherSuites(): Array<String> = internalSSLSocketFactory.supportedCipherSuites

    override fun createSocket(s: Socket, host: String, port: Int, autoClose: Boolean) =
            enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose))

    override fun createSocket(host: String, port: Int) =
            enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port))

    override fun createSocket(host: String, port: Int, localHost: InetAddress, localPort: Int) =
            enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort))

    override fun createSocket(host: InetAddress, port: Int) =
            enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port))

    override fun createSocket(address: InetAddress, port: Int, localAddress: InetAddress, localPort: Int) =
            enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort))

    private fun enableTLSOnSocket(socket: Socket?) = socket?.apply {
        if (this is SSLSocket && isTLSServerEnabled(this)) {
            enabledProtocols = protocols
        }
    }

    private fun isTLSServerEnabled(sslSocket: SSLSocket) = sslSocket.supportedProtocols.any { it in protocols }

}
```

Comment: HI, it did not work for me ,,any idea why ? will be great if you can help

Comment: I've been used your answer to establish MQTT SSL connection and it worked just fine! Thank you. #UP

Comment: @StoicaMircea this actually will make the connection using no ssl. 
this is not safe. you can use my workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47410689/how-to-use-a-self-signed-certificate-to-connect-to-a-mqtt-server-in-android-pah

Comment: @AmirZiarati , i've found later that you're right. I've also switched from `{TLS_v1_1, TLS_v1_2}` to `{TLS_v1_2, TLS_v1_1}` , to try first with TLS 1.2

Comment: good point ;) thanks. ill edit my answer based on your suggestion.

Comment: Just an implementation in kotlin https://gist.github.com/ademar111190/052de9e03f62bb0b2f4063c39774c79f

Comment: @carlol Thanks for this detailed answer. I am still running into one issue though, with this code, websites like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html will still throw an error ```javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found``` since the SSLContext is initialized with a null as the second param. I can force it to work by using a trust manager that accepts all certs, but that is dangerous. Any suggestions how to get this working with TLS1.2 on API levels 16-19?

Answer (score 10):

Add `play-services-safetynet` library in android `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:+'
```

and add this code to your `MainApplication.java`:

```
@Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    upgradeSecurityProvider();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }

  private void upgradeSecurityProvider() {
    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeededAsync(this, new ProviderInstallListener() {
      @Override
      public void onProviderInstalled() {

      }

      @Override
      public void onProviderInstallFailed(int errorCode, Intent recoveryIntent) {
//        GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorNotification(errorCode, MainApplication.this);
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorNotification(MainApplication.this, errorCode);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: This fixed my issue... error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Comment: also, remember to handle the following exception  GooglePlayServicesRepairableException and GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException as stated in the document https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider

Comment: can confirm this works well for react-native android 4.x implementation....

Answer (score 7):

You should use

```
 SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
```

for specific protocol version.

The second exception occured because default socketFactory used fallback SSLv3 protocol for failures.

You can use NoSSLFactory from main answer here for its suppression [How to disable SSLv3 in android for HttpsUrlConnection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649389/how-to-disable-sslv3-in-android-for-httpsurlconnection)

Also you should init SSLContext with all your certificates(client and trusted ones if you need them)

But all of that is useless without using

```
ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getContext())
```

Here is more information with proper usage scenario https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: According to this - http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.ektorp/org.ektorp.android/1.2.2/org/ektorp/android/http/AndroidSSLSocketFactory.java?av=h#AndroidSSLSocketFactory - only `"TLS"`, `"SSL"` and `"SSLV2"` are accepted.

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the issue with 4.1.2 clients

Comment: Maybe it's stupid but i've tried to add com.google.android lib in 4.0.1.2 version to my gradle and i cannot import com.google.android.gms.security.* So from which package you imports ProviderInstaller?

Answer (score 6):

I have some additions to above mentioned answers
Its infact a hack mentioned by Jesse Wilson from okhttp, square [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2323). According to this hack, i had to rename my SSLSocketFactory variable to

```
private SSLSocketFactory delegate;
```

This is my **TLSSocketFactory** class

```
public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

private SSLSocketFactory delegate;

public TLSSocketFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, null, null);
    delegate = context.getSocketFactory();
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    return delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket());
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
}

private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
    if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
        ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
    }
    return socket;
}
}
```

and this is how i used it with okhttp and retrofit

```
 OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
    try {
        client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .sslSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactory())
                .build();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Comment: This is the most helpful answer I have got. thanks, bro.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP said, TLS v1.1 and v1.2 protocols are supported in API level 16+, but are not enabled by default, we just need to enable it.

Example here uses `HttpsUrlConnection`, not `HttpUrlConnection`. Follow https://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/, we can create a factory

```
class MyFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

    public MyFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, null, null);
        internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket());
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
        if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
            ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
        }
        return socket;
    }
}
```

No matter which Networking library you use, make sure `((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});` gets called so the Socket has enabled TLS protocols.

Now, you can use that in `HttpsUrlConnection`

```
class MyHttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String my_url = params[0];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(my_url);
            HttpsURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(new MyFactory());
            // setting the  Request Method Type
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // adding the headers for request
            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");


            String result = readStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
            Log.e("My Networking", "We have data" + result.toString());


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("My Networking", "Oh no, error occurred " + e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static String readStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            reader.close();
        }
        return total.toString();
    }
}
```

For example

```
new MyHttpRequestTask().execute(myUrl);
```

Also, remember to bump `minSdkVersion` in build.gradle to 16

```
minSdkVersion 16
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: [Enable TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 in Android](https://github.com/codexpedia/android_enforce_tls1_2)

Answer (score -1):

@Inherently Curious - thanks for posting this. You are almost there - you have to add two more params to SSLContext.init() method.

```
TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[] { new TrustManagerManipulator() };
sc.init(null, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
```

it will start working. Again thank you very much for posting this. I solved this/my issue with your code.

Comment: I must have missed it, but where does TrustManagerManipulator class come from?