# TLS 1.1 @ TLS 1.2 on httpclientandroidlib

Tags: java, android, ssl, https

During developing Android application I faced a problem with SSL connection in android lower than KIT KAT.

Application is using **ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib** to connect. When I tried to get httpConnection I'm getting error:

here was error during executing http request.

```
  javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

In Android newest than KIT KAT everything works fine.

I'm trying to use solution sugested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943660/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-support-in-an-android-application-running-on-android-4-1) but i have a problem with casting types from **ch.boye.httpclientandroidlib** to apache elements in my current implemetations.

Is there any solution for using this library for android lower than KIT KAT?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this same issue [here](https://github.com/erickok/transdroid/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/transdroid/daemon/util/TlsSniSocketFactory.java)... using the class **TlsSniSocketFactory** (you'll have to also download **IgnoreSSLTrustManager** and **SelfSignedTrustManager** from the same "util" folder) and add it to your project.
Then register the new scheme on your SchemeRegistry object like so:

```
schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", new TlsSniSocketFactory(), port));
```

My issue was my web service is set to use TLS 1.2 only.
Android devices running Android 4.4.4 and below do not automatically enable TLS 1.2 so you have to manually enable it (***IMPORTANT*** * devices older than Android 4.1 cannot support TLS 1.2 at all, so this solution wont work for those older devices)

Late answer but hopefully helps someone

Cheers

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!! 
On device Android 4.4.4 as you described.