# Retrofit is not working below Lollipop

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to get data from my website using `Retrofit`. It's working fine from Android 5.0 but lesser android version showing error message `Connection closed by peer`. Here is my code...

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://myWebsite.com/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
service = retrofit.create(MyService.class);
```

And here is `MyService` class

```
@GET
Call<CategoryResponse> getCategoryResponse(@Url String url);
```

What am I missing here? It's completely working fine over Android 5.0. I think it is something to deal with SSL Handshake and `OkHttpClient`. I don't know how to implement `OkHttpClient` with `Retrofit`.

Here is my logcat

```
 06-29 10:50:49.906 10438-10438/com.dualbrotech.playwithprizes E/dalvikvm:       Could not find class 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$1', referenced  from method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.<init>
06-29 10:50:49.914 10438-10438/com.dualbrotech.playwithprizes E/dalvikvm:  Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method  android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onDraw
06-29 10:50:49.917 10438-10438/com.dualbrotech.playwithprizes E/dalvikvm:  Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method  android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure
06-29 10:50:49.918 10438-10438/com.dualbrotech.playwithprizes E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.WindowInsets', referenced from method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure
06-29 10:50:51.219 10438-10611/com.dualbrotech.playwithprizes   E/NativeCrypto: Unknown error during handshake
06-29 10:50:52.194 10438-10615/com.dualbrotech.playwithprizes E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x541654b8 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x540adab8 arg=0x0
ssl=0x541654b8 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
06-29 10:50:52.254 10438-10618/com.dualbrotech.playwithprizes E/NativeCrypto: Unknown error during handshake
06-29 10:50:52.296 10438-10438/com.dualbrotech.playwithprizes E/error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
06-29 10:51:31.769 10438-10618/com.dualbrotech.playwithprizes E/NativeCrypto: Unknown error during handshake
06-29 10:51:35.491 10438-10618/com.dualbrotech.playwithprizes E/NativeCrypto: Unknown error during handshake
06-29 10:51:35.503 10438-10438/com.dualbrotech.playwithprizes E/error: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
```

Comment: you are missing your `service.getCategoryResponse.enqueue(Call)`?

Comment: no, it's working fine from android 5.0 if i miss that how can it worked.

Comment: There is insufficient information to go about, post the code on `enqueue` and your error log

Comment: @HawkPriest enqueue is ok. i figured out it has something to deal with OkHttpClient. The problem is happening for the SSL security. For lower android version retrofit must be configured with OkHttpClient. But i don't know how to do it.

Comment: If that's the case then you need to ask your API provider to update the certificates check out this on their issue page https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3188

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android pre-lollipop devices giving error "SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x618d9c18: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984295/android-pre-lollipop-devices-giving-error-ssl-handshake-aborted-ssl-0x618d9c18)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not clear without the proper logcat. However, looks like you have SSL certificate issues with your API server. You might consider managing a valid SSL certificate for your API server which will remove the error I think.

As a workaround, you might consider trusting all certificates which are not safe, as [described here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-trust-unsafe-ssl-certificates-self-signed-expired).

I am copying the code from the tutorial for convenience.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = UnsafeOkHttpClient.getUnsafeOkHttpClient();

Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()  
        .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

UserService userClient = retrofit.create(UserService.class);

Call<ResponseBody> call = userClient.profilePicture("https://revoked.badssl.com/");  
call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {  
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        Toast.makeText(BadSSLActivity.this, "got response" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(BadSSLActivity.this, "SSL error?" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Please go through the tutorial for better understanding. Hope that helps.

Comment: I added my logcat. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

If you go through the official documentation of [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), it says that **"Retrofit requires at minimum Java 8+ or Android API 21+."**, where API 21 is the lollipop version. So anything below that will remain unsupported.