# Retrofit API failure on pre 21 API devices javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:

Tags: android, api, ssl, retrofit, protocols

I got following error :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x795c2a18: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x72728cfc:0x00000000)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android pre-lollipop devices giving error "SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x618d9c18: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984295/android-pre-lollipop-devices-giving-error-ssl-handshake-aborted-ssl-0x618d9c18)

Comment: Refer this solution: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46025698/9763253)

Comment: @UmangBurman not working.

Comment: Could You paste the updated code please?