# SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xae8414e8: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, android, ssl

Everything was working fine until I installed SSL certificate on my websites now i get this error when connecting to c# web api using IIS 10 from android . My code works on android 6 and above but not on android 4.
Here is my code

```
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    List<File> mFiles=new ArrayList<>();

    String urlString = Common.URL+"SaveImage";

    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
        final List<FileBody> mFileBody=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<Common.ImagePathList.size();i++){
            FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(new File(Common.ImagePathList.get(i)));
            mFileBody.add(bin1);
        }
        Looper.prepare();
        MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        reqEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        for(int i=0;i<  mFileBody.size();i++){
            reqEntity.addPart("Photo"+i,mFileBody.get(i));
        }

        //  reqEntity.addTextBody("size",""+Common.ImagePathList.size(), cz.msebera.android.httpclient.entity.ContentType.parse(ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        reqEntity.addTextBody("adId",Common.AdId);
        post.setEntity((HttpEntity) reqEntity.build());

        //socketFactory.createSocket().connect(client.);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
        final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

        if (resEntity != null) {
            Log.i("RESPONSE", response_str);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        mFileBody.clear();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }});
            return response_str;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+ ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I tried postman and to see if it was server issue but it works fine in postman but copying the java auto code from postman doesn't work in android and produced `Response code 400`

Thanks in advance

Comment: The issue is possibly because the api endpoint supports only TLS 1.2 which is disabled by default on android devices 16<device<20 . So for 16<device<20, create a custom SSLSocketFactory, like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46025698/8009433