# SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xbe6af938: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, android, ssl, retrofit2

The following error occurs: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xbe6af938: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer`

Retrofit class:

```
public class RetrofitClientInstance {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        
        if (retrofit == null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();

            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(HelperOkHttpClient.getOkHttpClient())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

The error / exception appears in this method:

```
private void makeRequestToSecondAuthStep(ArrayList<String> creds) {

        AuthCheckHTTP defectSpecific = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(AuthCheckHTTP.class);
        Observable<ResponseSingleRequestAuth<Object>> observableDefectsRelated = defectSpecific.getAuthCheck();
        observableDefectsRelated
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnNext(specficDefects -> {
                    Log.w("ASYNCLI", "In defectspecif");
                    if (HelperIsNull.isNull(creds.get(3))) {
                        creds.set(3, creds.get(5));
                    }
                    DataBaseHelper.deleteAllData();
                    PublisherNotificationSync.getInstance().setLastSyncDate(INITIAL_DATE);
                    writeCredentialsToLocalDb();

                    actMain.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                              @Override
                                              public void run() {
                                                  presenterAuthAct.downloadData();
                                              }
                                          }
                    );
                })
                .doOnError(
                        throwable -> {
                            ...
                        }
                ).doOnComplete(() -> {
        }).subscribe(new Observer<ResponseSingleRequestAuth<Object>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(ResponseSingleRequestAuth<Object> objectResponseSingleRequestAuth) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
              // do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Maybe somehow you can add standards (SSL) to this Retrofit class, could anyone have encountered this or a similar problem before?

What could be the problem? A few months ago - everything worked, the project was not touched (archived)
Thank you in advance

**UPD: nothing to do with the certificate, this is SAP, they update themselves**

Comment: This is not app related issue....Check server certificates and expire date....

Comment: Check your server ssl error using this link https://www.ssllabs.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's enough info here for me to accurately diagnose your problem but the error indicates an SSL handshake error, which would normally, to me, indicate the problem isn't in the code, but in the certs/acceptable encryption algorithms for the communication channel.

Retrofit is a REST framework, so I'm assuming you wrote an API on top of it and retrofit handles your HTTP sessions and SSL stuff. You said the solution suddenly stopped working. Is your retrofit dependency up to date? Maybe bring your dependencies up to date, repackage your application and see if that works?

[Retrofit/OkHTTP examples with TLS Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984295/android-pre-lollipop-devices-giving-error-ssl-handshake-aborted-ssl-0x618d9c18)

Comment: retrofit has been updated to the latest version, so hardly a dependency issue

Comment: what about your server certificate? You said several months have passed, is the certificate still valid? If it is expired, you'll need to issue a new one.

Comment: I spoke with a backing specialist, he said "there is nothing to update there", since this is SAP and they do everything themselves

Comment: It sounds like you are acting as the client and not the server. Can you post the portion of your code where you create your SSLContext object?

Comment: no, since there is no such class in the application at all (

Comment: I kind of created a TSLFactory class, where SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance ("TLS") is written;
But I don't quite understand how and where to connect it from retrofit?

Comment: What happens if you change "TLS" on that line to "TLSv1.2"?

Comment: You should use TLSv1.2 in that factory but you're also wondering how to implement the factory. I'll post a link with some examples in my answer.

Comment: I have considered such an option as you suggested,
The problem is that I didn't know how to connect it to my class )