# OkHttp Response is null only on Android 4.4

Tags: android, rest, okhttp

This is a strange behaviour: I am using OkHttp3 to handle my rest api calls from the app. 
Everything works fine on Android 5+ but when on Android 4.4 every request fails.

I tried to debug with `com.github.simonpercic.oklog3.OkLogInterceptor` but it the response seems empty.

The rest api is under SSL and I add `Authentication` headers for basic login.

Can someone help me?

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code and log output?

Comment: What TLS version do you use on the server? If the answer is "1.2" have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943660/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-support-in-an-android-application-running-on-android-4-1)

Comment: Yes, it is TLS 1.2. I think I should enable 1.0 on server side in order to fix it quickly (then I could plan an app upgrade). I'd never thought about this!