# How to ensure TLS 1.2 is used in API request from Android Volley?

Tags: android, api, android-volley, tls1.2

I am required to make all API calls to a server using TLS 1.2. I am using volley (v1.1.1) with minSDKversion 21. How is it possible to ensure that all calls are done with TLS 1.2?

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

Add play-services-safetynet library in android build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:+'
```

and add this code to your MainApplication.java:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    upgradeSecurityProvider();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }

  private void upgradeSecurityProvider() {
    ProviderInstaller.installIfNeededAsync(this, new ProviderInstallListener() {
      @Override
      public void onProviderInstalled() {

      }

      @Override
      public void onProviderInstallFailed(int errorCode, Intent recoveryIntent) {
//        GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorNotification(errorCode, MainApplication.this);
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorNotification(MainApplication.this, errorCode);
      }
    });
  }
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55365051/5320349

Comment: tnx, I will try it now. But to be sure - should I use Volley request inside onProviderInstalled()? or just paste the code below in mainActivity () and it will "make all the app use tls"?

Comment: and what is SoLoader.init? what should I write inistead of /*native exopackage*/?