# How to enable/support TLS 1.1,1.2 for Exoplayer?

Tags: android, tls1.2, exoplayer

Error:
SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x676a5680: **Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error**

According to this [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket#protocols), **TLS 1.1** and **1.2** is supported on API 16+ but not enabled by default until API 20+. I found some solutions([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943660/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-support-in-an-android-application-running-on-android-4-1), [here](https://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/), [here](https://ankushg.com/posts/tls-1.2-on-android/) and [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2372#issuecomment-244807676)) for enabling TLS 1.1 and 1.2 support for OkHttp. How can I enable the TLS 1.1/1.2 support for Exoplayer? The only post I found for Exoplayer TLS 1.1/1.2 support is from this github [issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4589) which suggested to ask the question here instead.

> "07-27 13:21:09.817 8925-9065/com.ftsgps.monarch
>   E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException:
>   Unable to connect to https://liveStream/LIVE-0089000D05/manifest.mpd
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:194)
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:147)
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:102)
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:65)
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:129)
>   at
>   com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:308)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) Caused by:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:
>   ssl=0x722c3af8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>   error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert
>   handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744
>   0x689d8f10:0x00000000)"
>
> This is happening only below API 21 version (lollipop). Server is
>   using TLS1.2 protocol, which isn't support on Android below Lollipop
>   version.

Comment: First it would be nice to have MVCE so we could try it out.  From what I have checked the issue is similar to OkHttp in that you need to patch Exoplayer silmilar way the OkHttp was in the github post you have linked - https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2372#issuecomment-244807676

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging around, all I have to do is to enable the TLS1.2 in the application class using the [ProviderInstaller](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html). I've verified it with server serving video content that don't accept TLS1.0, and it worked.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        try {
          // Google Play will install latest OpenSSL 
          ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());
          SSLContext sslContext;
          sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
          sslContext.init(null, null, null);
          sslContext.createSSLEngine();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:

[Javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916962/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-ssl-han/30302235#30302235)

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-OkHttp#enabling-tls-v1-2-on-older-devices

Answer (score 5):

`DefaultHttpDataSource` uses `HttpsURLConnection` which has a static field for default `SSLSocketFactory`. All new instances of `HttpsURLConnection` will have this default `SSLSocketFactory` assigned unless `setSSLSocketFactory()` is called on an instance. So technically, if you call set the default `SSLSocketFactory` **before** instantiating `DefaultHttpsDataSource`, it should work:

```java
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(new MyCustomSSLSocketFactory());
```

where `MyCustomSSLSocketFactoy` may look something like this:

```
class MyCustomSSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

    private javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

    public MyCustomSSLSocketFactory () throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, null, null);
        internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket());
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
        if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
            ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
        }
        return socket;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind however that this may change behavior of your app in unexpected places (highly unlikely but never hurts to be cautious), In order to avoid that, you can revert back the Default SSLSocketFactory to old one after using your `DefaultHttpDataSource`.

**However, there is another more reliable solution.**
You can use `OkHttpDataSource` where you can pass an `OkHttpClient` instance in the constructor. This `OkHttpClient` instance can be configured to use our custom `SSLSocketFactory`. It would look something like this:

```
okhttpclient.sslSocketFactory(new MyCustomSSLSocketFactory());
```

```java
DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(context, bandwidthMeter,
    new OkHttpDataSource(okHttpClient, userAgent, null, bandwidthMeter));
```

Comment: Verified this worked by setting `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(new MyCustomSSLSocketFactory());` first thing in the onCreate() in the Application class.  However, I used ProviderInstaller instead as it is less code, at a higher level and no need to mess with the socket factory.

Comment: uh.. where does bandwidthMeter come from?

Comment: I guess it has something to do with media playback. You can see it's in ExoPlayer by calling `new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).setBandwidthMeter()`