# TLS sessions are not supported on Native platform

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I'm getting a "TLS sessions are not supported on Native platform" message

I'm building an application using KMP (KMM previously) and I'll have to send some requests to an API. This is how I'm sending the request:

```
class Greeting {
    suspend fun sendLoginRequest(email: String, password: String):ResponseResult {
        return try {
            val client = HttpClient(CIO)
            val response: HttpResponse = client.submitForm(
                url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments",
                formParameters = parameters {
                    append("email", email)
                    append("password", password)
                }
            )
            val responseBody = response.bodyAsText()
            ResponseResult(responseBody, null)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            ResponseResult(null, e.message ?: "An unknown error occurred.")
        }
    }
}
```

And the following code is how I'm using it in Android App:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Loading") }
LaunchedEffect(true) {

    // Call the function with a callback
    text = Greeting().sendLoginRequest("example@email.com", "strangePass").response.toString()
}
Text(text = text)
```

and it's working very fine, but on iOS it's not. This is how I'm using it in SwiftUI:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var email = "email@example.com"
    var password = "strangePass"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.text)
            .onAppear {
            Task {
                let result = try await Greeting().sendLoginRequest(email: email, password: password)
                if let response = result.response {
                self.viewModel.text = response
                } else if let error = result.error {
                self.viewModel.text = error
                } else {
                self.viewModel.text = "An unknown error occurred."
                }
            }
            }
    }
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var text = "Loading..."
    
    func login(email: String, password: String) async {
    do {
        let result = try await Greeting().sendLoginRequest(email: email, password: password)
        if let response = result.response {
        self.text = response
        } else if let error = result.error {
        self.text = error
        } else {
        self.text = "An unknown error occurred."
        }
    } catch {
        self.text = "An error occurred: \(error.localizedDescription)"
    }
    }
}
```

As [This](https://github.com/joreilly/PeopleInSpace/issues/69#issuecomment-888618598) said, I have to use `http` instead of `https` and it actually worked, but this can't be a solution as it's less secure and not recommended.

And I've tried to refer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28943660/how-to-enable-tls-1-2-support-in-an-android-application-running-on-android-4-1) but it didn't seem to fix it either.

I've also tried to modify the `info.plist` file and added the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>jsonplaceholder.typicode.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

But it is still not fixed.

### Edit

This is my grade file

```
listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "shared"
        }
    }

    val ktorVersion = "2.3.4"

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }

        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies{
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.2")
            }
        }

        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)

            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }

        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What isn’t working? What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, looks like I didn't include the message in the body part, it was only on the title.

I'm getting "TLS sessions are not supported on Native platform"

Comment: That isn’t an iOS error, that is something with whatever package you are using. iOS does support https by default

Comment: Yes, I know that. When I provide the API link from the Swift code it works fine, but when it's in the shared folder, it doesn't. That's my point. I thought the problem was from the server of my API, but I tried another placeholder API link such as `jsonplaceholder` or `worldtimeapi`

Comment: You should tag the package that is throwing the error see if someone knows of a setting for it, I don’t think this is a swift thing at all. The issue is with your package not supporting TLS for some reason it wants you to disable Transport Security, I would question the safety of that package.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you very well but, in the shared module in Kotlin, I'm using the Ktor library as it's built on Kotlin to support KMP because we can't use Java libraries for iOS.

Comment: I tagged Ktor for you, there might be setting for this issue someone more familiar can maybe help.

Comment: which ktor engine are you using for `iosMain`? Do you have something in your gradle file such as `implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:$ktorVersion")`

Comment: @Sjolfr Yes, iosMain and I do have the darwin implementation

Answer (score 1):

On the [official documentation here](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html#default), the recommendation is call the HttpClient constructor without passing in the specific engine to have the client select the engine automatically - assuming the dependencies for iOS and Android are already set up correctly (e.g. `Darwin` for `iOSMain` and `okHttp` for `androidMain`).

Have you tried using `val client = HttpClient()` instead of the `val client = HttpClient(CIO)` as shown on your code snippet?

Comment: I haven't tried that tbh, but I'll try it on my new project, thanks for the help 

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use the `CIO` engine instead of the `Darwin` engine:

```
class Greeting {
    suspend fun sendLoginRequest(email: String, password: String):ResponseResult {
        return try {
            val client = HttpClient(CIO) // Put Darwin instead of CIO here
            // ...
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            ResponseResult(null, e.message ?: "An unknown error occurred.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try to do that, thank you