# How to use Https on android 5.0 Lollipop to communicate with server which use TLSV1.2

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, tls1.2

Running on android 5 Lollipop, I am trying to get a response from my server which uses TLSv1.2, but I got this error log bellow. The same code works on both android 4 and android 6. How can I solve this problem?

```
05-23 10:25:46.221: W/System.err(5945): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
05-23 10:25:46.221: W/System.err(5945):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:374)
05-23 10:25:46.222: W/System.err(5945):     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:197)
05-23 10:25:46.222: W/System.err(5945):     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:151)
05-23 10:25:46.225: W/System.err(5945):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
05-23 10:25:46.226: W/System.err(5945):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
05-23 10:25:46.226: W/System.err(5945):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
05-23 10:25:46.226: W/System.err(5945):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
05-23 10:25:46.226: W/System.err(5945):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:190)
05-23 10:25:46.226: W/System.err(5945):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
05-23 10:25:46.226: W/System.err(5945):     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
05-23 10:25:46.227: W/System.err(5945):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-23 10:25:46.227: W/System.err(5945): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x6f4cc600: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
05-23 10:25:46.227: W/System.err(5945): error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:735 0x6be81ee1:0x00000000)
05-23 10:25:46.231: W/System.err(5945):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
05-23 10:25:46.231: W/System.err(5945):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:302)
05-23 10:25:46.232: W/System.err(5945):     ... 12 more
```

and this is my code

```
public static void getWithoutCertificate() {
    String url = "https://thapi.bluepay.asia/blue/gateWay/doProcess/service_queryTrans?operatorId=2&productid=177&t_id=gasq20160519153044zD&encrypt=30001721bd69594aa09b30ccaebb7683";
    StringBuffer bufferRes = null;
    try {
        TrustManager[] tm = { new MyX509TrustManager() }; 
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(null, tm, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        // get SSLSocketFactory from the sslContext above
        javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory ssf = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        URL _url = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) _url
                .openConnection();
        // trust any hostname
        httpsURLConnection
                .setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
        httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(ssf);
        httpsURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(25000);
        httpsURLConnection.setReadTimeout(25000);
        httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpsURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httpsURLConnection
                .setRequestProperty(
                        "User-Agent",
                        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36");
        httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpsURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpsURLConnection.connect();
        InputStream in = httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,
                "utf-8"));
        String valueString = null;
        bufferRes = new StringBuffer();
        while ((valueString = read.readLine()) != null) {
            bufferRes.append(valueString);
        }
        in.close();
        if (httpsURLConnection != null) {
            httpsURLConnection.disconnect();// close connection
        }
        Log.i(TAG, bufferRes.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
// an inner class 
private static class MyX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
            throws CertificateException {
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of server is this?

Comment: Can you show us the code which opens the connection?

Comment: You need to disable SSLv2 and SSLv3. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34904758/150978) how to do it.

Comment: @DanielS. i just post my code bellow the error log :)

Comment: @Robert thx, i'll check the answer