# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException on Android 4.3

Tags: android, ssl, tls1.2, okhttp

Unfortunately I've stucked on getting my app able to use TLS 1.2 protocol on Android version < 5.0. 
I use okhttp3 library for creating and firing up proper requests. Everything works perfect on devices running Lollipop +. 
I am building OkHttpClient instance like this:

```
 SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS"); // tried TLSv1.2
    context.init(null, trustManagers, null);

    List<ConnectionSpec> specs = new ArrayList<>();
    specs.add(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS);
    specs.add(ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                  .sslSocketFactory(new TlsSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory()), (X509TrustManager)trustManagers[0])
                                  .connectionSpecs(specs)
                                  .build();
```

Inside TlsSocketFactory class I am setting enabled protocols:

```
  private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
    if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
        ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
    }
    return socket;
}
```

After executing request i get this issue:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x67531570: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x5dfc97e8:0x00000000)
```

I have made a lot of research about this kind of issue, but unfortunately none of presented solutions did the trick. I have already tried:

- Installing proper security provider [link](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider)
- Creating TLSSocketFactory class (similar is presented here: [link](https://blog.dev-area.net/2015/08/13/android-4-1-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2/))
- Creating NoSSLv3SocketFactory class (presented as solution here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649389/how-to-disable-sslv3-in-android-for-httpsurlconnection))
- Checking if sever uses proper ciphers (and it does)

Curious thing is calling `getSupportedSSLParameters().getProtocols()` returns [SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2] but calling `getDefaultSSLParameters().getProtocols()` returns only [SSLv3, TLSv1]
Do you guys have any ideas about this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `MODERN_TLS` with `COMPATIBLE_TLS`. That is necessary to enable obsolete TLS versions.

See [OkHttp’s HTTPS page](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/HTTPS) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately response is still the same.