# Volley error code 400 in android version below 4.4

Tags: android, https, android-volley

I am trying to call a web service (https) using Volley and I am getting an error code 400.

I am using GET method. All web services including this are working properly in android version above 4.4.

Most confusing part is that, all other web services are working properly in 4.0.4 and if I try multiple times even this particular web service which is having the issue works properly (second or third time). I have noticed that other web services which are using the same method are also working properly.

Initially I was facing an SSLHandshakeException in android versions below 4.4, which I corrected based on the answer in the link given below:

[Javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916962/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-ssl-han)

But now I am facing this particular issue. I have checked the URL in postman and it is working fine.