# UrlConnection : SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x631b60c8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

Tags: java, android, ssl, https, urlconnection

I am currently working on the migration of an Android from HttpClient to UrlConnection. I am facing some issue on, at least, Android 4.2.2.

The URL I am trying to call to is an https URL and I have to use a client certificate.

Based on [this blog article](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/https-with-client-certificates-on/), I wrote the following code :

```
// We create the client PKCS12 certificate
final KeyStore clientCertificateKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
try
{
  clientCertificateKeyStore.load(this.clientCertificatePayload, this.clientCertificatePassword.toCharArray());
}
finally
{
  this.clientCertificatePayload.close();
}

final KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
keyManagerFactory.init(clientCertificateKeyStore, clientCertificatePassword.toCharArray());

final KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagers, null, null);
```

And later in my code, I use the `sslContext` variable to set the SSL Factory my `httpURLConnection` :

```
((HttpsURLConnection) httpURLConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

This code works perfectly on my Nexus 5 with Android 6.0.1 but does not work on a Wiko Rainbow with Android 4.2.2. In fact, after setting the sslSocketFactory to my `httpURLConnection`, I have the following exception when I call the `getOutputStream` method :

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x631b60c8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x59b4c8a8:0x00000000)
   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:421)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.setupSecureSocket(HttpConnection.java:209)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:450)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:205)
   at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:281)
   at com.splunk.mint.network.http.MonitorableHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(MonitorableHttpsURLConnection.java:93)
   at com.smartnsoft.droid4me.ws.URLConnectionWebServiceCaller.performHttpRequest(URLConnectionWebServiceCaller.java:472)
   at com.smartnsoft.droid4me.ws.URLConnectionWebServiceCaller.performHttpRequest(URLConnectionWebServiceCaller.java:562)
   at com.smartnsoft.droid4me.ws.URLConnectionWebServiceCaller.getInputStream(URLConnectionWebServiceCaller.java:158)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x631b60c8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x59b4c8a8:0x00000000)
   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHand
```

I tried several solutions including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916962/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-ssl-han) but I still have the exception.

Do you have any idea how to make the code working on Android 4.2.2 ?

Thank you for your help !

**Edit :** Here the way I use the `NoSSLv3Factory`.

Basically, I use the same code to create the client PKCS12 certificate  and initialize the the `SSLContext`. The difference is when I set the `SSLSocketFactory` to my `HttpUrlConnection`. Here the condition I tried to use :

```
if (httpURLConnection instanceof HttpsURLConnection)
{
  if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  {
    ((HttpsURLConnection) httpURLConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
  }
  else
  {
    ((HttpsURLConnection) httpURLConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(new NoSSLv3Factory());
  }
```

}

I also tried to use another version of the constructor using the code :

```
((HttpsURLConnection) httpURLConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(new NoSSLv3Factory(sslContext.getSocketFactory()));
```

But I still have the same exception :(

Comment: What happens when you use that NoSSLv3SocketFactory class? Same result?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916962/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-ssl-han

Comment: @DanielNugent : Thx for your help. Yes, I have the same exception. I have edited my post with a code sample to show how I use the `NoSSLv3Factory` class.

Comment: @RohitSharma I also tried the solution of you link but I still have the issue :(

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?