# How to recompile native HttpClient module in Titanium?

Tags: java, android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've got a problem.
I'm using Titanium SDK 5.1.1.GA and on Android I experience that issue:
[Description of error on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916962/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-ssl-han)

I checked Titanium SDK source and found that class: TiSocketFactory.java

[The code of that class can be found here](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/bc85170157d3bebc5de1d61a9fe6e34bce84a8c9/android/modules/network/src/java/ti/modules/titanium/network/TiSocketFactory.java)

How can I change the source code of that class and than to use it in my application?

Answer (score 0):

The process of modifying the [Titanium SDK source code](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile) and building it from source is described in [this guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Building_the_Titanium_SDK_From_Source).

Answer (score -1):

Right now you would need to create a [Titanium Module](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Module_Development_Guide) for Android. If your looking to experiment, you could also use [Hyperloop](http://labs.appcelerator.com/project/55f74a9f421c44837717716b/Hyperloop-Module) to access those APIs directly.

The Titanium Module framework, allows you to extend your Titanium application using native Java. From Appcelerator Studio or CLI, you would create a new Titanium Module project, specifying Android as your target platform. This will generate a module project for you which you can then leverage the code found in the Titanium source to scaffold what your looking to do.

Hyperloop is new tech, and still in beta for iOS and Android (its GA with Windows),  but allows you to leverage the Android native APIs directly from JavaScript. You can find sample code in the link to Hyperloop above.

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: The problem is not to create new native module but to modify in-house Appcelerator's HttpClient module.