# Implement Paypal Express Checkout in Xamarin-Forms

Tags: c#, paypal, xamarin.forms

I am working with E-Commerce Xamarin-forms application.I want to Implement **Paypal Express Checkout** in my app when user is about to checkout.I am referring to [this](https://github.com/henev/xamarin-paypal-express-checkout) sample but I am getting **Security channel failure** error.
I have also added..

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (o, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

but still I am getting the same error.

How to Implement paypal express checkout in xamarin forms ? Please Help !

Comment: is that happened on android only?

Comment: I haven't tried in ios yet

Comment: What Android OS version do you try? As I remember I get this trouble when test in API 16-19. But in API 20 it works well... Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222696/sslhandshakeexception-on-android-4-4-and-lower

Comment: I am testing it in API-23

Comment: try use modernhttpclient then in your pcl and also all your project