# javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException

Tags: java, android, ssl

I have been testing locally on https.
This is my code

```
private static void disableSSLCertificateChecking() {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }
    } };

    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this is how i am requesting

```
        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {

            if(Some condition){
                disableSSLCertificateChecking();

                URL url = new URL(host+"discovery.jsp");
                HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
```

I get the exception at conn.getOutputStream().i was using httpclient previously.And i am having problems migrating now.'
Please help.

This is how i was using it before.

```
private static void disableSSLCertificateChecking() {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }
    } };

    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {           
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {            
    }
}
```

and

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

    try {

        if(Some condition){
            disableSSLCertificateChecking();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(host + "discovery.jsp");

                SSLSocketFactory sf = (SSLSocketFactory)httpClient.getConnectionManager()
                        .getSchemeRegistry().getScheme("https").getSocketFactory();
                sf.setHostnameVerifier(new AllowAllHostnameVerifier());                    
                HttpResponse response = null;

                try {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {                                              
                }

                //making POST request.
                try {                  
                    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

EDIT
StackTrace

```
W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x55b145a0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
W/System.err: error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:714 0x524aed74:0x00000000)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:449)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:89)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
W/System.err:     at com.sixdee.verifiedcpisdk.j.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.sixdee.verifiedcpisdk.j.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x55b145a0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
W/System.err: error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:714 0x524aed74:0x00000000)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:406)
W/System.err:   ... 17 more
```

Comment: Could you maybe also provide a stacktrace?

Comment: You are trying to create an SSLv2/SSLv3 connection to a server that only accepts TLS connections. May be the device uses an old Android version? You should check what protocols are enabled on your SSLSocketFactory. BTW: Disabling half of the security of SSL/TLS is not a good idea (accept all certificates, disable HostNameVerifier)...

Comment: Duplicate question > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916962/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-ssl-han