# SSL Handshake Excetion : Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

Tags: java, android, ssl, java-websocket, sslhandshakeexception

I am using a physical device with android v4.4.2 (Java) with [java_websockets](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) and I get this error when attempting to connect to the websocket.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: 
SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7aa38588: 
Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:
unknown protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:769 0x73a81cfc:0x00000000)
```

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916962/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-ssl-han) and I tried implementing it but nothing changes. That is where I get the code for `NoSSLv3SocketFactory`. It goes into the try catch until the last line `mWebSocketClient.connect()` but it doesn't go into the catch, the `onError` logs the error.

This is the websocket setup code.

```
...
String complete = wsBase + ep;
URI uri = new URI(complete);

mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri, new Draft_17()) 
{
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) 
            {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) 
            {
                final String message = s;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                        Log.i("onMessage", "running");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) 
            {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) 
            {
                Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };

        try 
        {
            // Stuff I thought might have fixed it but didn't
            SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");

            sslcontext.init(null,
                    null,
                    null);
            SSLSocketFactory noSSLv3Factory = new NoSSLv3SocketFactory(sslcontext.getSocketFactory());

            Socket socket = noSSLv3Factory.createSocket(uri.getHost(), 80);
            mWebSocketClient.setSocket(socket);
            mWebSocketClient.connect();
        } 

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("Websocket", e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         Socket socket = noSSLv3Factory.createSocket(uri.getHost(), 80);
> ```

If I understand your code correctly you are trying to connect to a secure WebSocket on port 80. While in theory somebody could setup a server like this it is very unlikely. Port 80 is used for http not https and thus for `ws://` and not `wss://. Secure Websockets (`wss://`) are usually handled on port 443 where also https is done.

Comment: For testing purposes, it doesn't matter if it is secure or not. The (internal)  server I am connecting to is not secured and is http, not https.

Comment: In other words, I am just trying achieve any connection at all to work on other things in the app.

Comment: @CookieMonster: If the internal server is http only you cannot do a secure websocket connection. While I personally have no experience with this library it looks like that there are examples so you should base your experiments on an example which does not use SSL.

Comment: So all this stuff was an attempted fix for a different issue, turns out in my initial problem was that I was using `SSLSocketFactory` instead of `SocketFactory` to fix yet another issue. Now this error is gone ... back to my initial other problem ... Don't worry about it, thanks though