# Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error

Tags: android, ssl

I know there are many similar question about ssl certificate in stackoverflow. I looked all these question but I did not fix issue. I'm trying to https connection using ssl certificate. I'm following android documentation 
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html. 
This is my code :

```
        ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this)
        val cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
        val caInput = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.cert)
        val ca: Certificate
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput)
        } finally {
            caInput.close()
        }
        val keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType()
        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType)
        keyStore.load(null, null)
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca)

        val tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm()
        val tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm)
        tmf.init(keyStore)

        val kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509")
        kmf.init(keyStore, pass.toCharArray())
        val trustAllCerts = arrayOf<TrustManager>(object : X509TrustManager {
            override fun getAcceptedIssuers(): Array<X509Certificate> {
                return arrayOf<X509Certificate>();
            }
            override fun checkClientTrusted(p0: Array<out X509Certificate>?, p1: String?) {
            }
            override fun checkServerTrusted(p0: Array<out X509Certificate>?, p1: String?) {
            }
        })
        val context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1")
        context.init(kmf.keyManagers, trustAllCerts, java.security.SecureRandom())
        val socketFactory = context.socketFactory
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
        doAsync {
            val url = URL(sourceUrl)
            val urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
            val `in` = urlConnection.inputStream
        }
```

I'm getting SSLProtocolException :

> ```
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted:
> ```
>
> ssl=0x5266a740: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
>       W: error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:714 0x52587f10:0x00000000)
>       W:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:448)
>       W:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
>       W:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
>       W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
>       W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
>       W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
>       W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
>       W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
>       W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
>       W:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
>       W:     at com.triomobil.triotys.pinning.PinningActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(PinningActivity.kt:142)
>       W:     at com.triomobil.triotys.pinning.PinningActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(PinningActivity.kt:33)
>       W:     at org.jetbrains.anko.AsyncKt$doAsync$1.invoke(Async.kt:140)
>       W:     at org.jetbrains.anko.AsyncKt$doAsync$1.invoke(Async.kt)
>       W:     at org.jetbrains.anko.AsyncKt$sam$Callable$761a5578.call(Async.kt)
>       W:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>       W:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
>       W:     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
>       W:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>       W:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>       W:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>       W: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5266a740: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol
>   error
>       W: error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:714 0x52587f10:0x00000000)
>       W:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>       W:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:406)
>       W:    ... 20 more

I'm looking all similar question stackoverflow . I tried everything but it did not work.

Comment: *"...unsupported protocol... "* - this means that the server does not support the SSL/TLS protocol you are using ("TLSv1"). This has nothing to do with certificates. Please check what protocols your server supports and make sure they match what you expect.

Comment: My server does support TLSv1.1.

Comment: A packet capture (tcpdump, wireshark ...  - upload to cloudshark.org) might be useful to further debug the problem. With a packet capture one could see the details of the handshake and maybe find out why it fails.

Comment: I encountered this on API 16 emulator. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916962/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-ssl-han.