# Android HttpsUrlConnection failed sometimes

Tags: android, httpsurlconnection

I am trying https url connection with following code

```
 HttpsURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) objectURL.openConnection();
           
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(httpConnection.getOutputStream());
            dStream.writeBytes(urlParameters);
```

somtime its working ,but most of time failing with following is the error message

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xe1101788: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
W/System.err: error:100000df:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE (external/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake_client.cc:1015 0xd33f6543:0x00000000)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:387)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:226)
W/System.err:   ... 21 more

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916962/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-ssl-han

Comment: Already tried its not resolved